# "Правительство объявило, когда победит бедность". Как называется этот тип ошибки?

Tags: грамотная-речь, типы-ошибок

Сегодняшний заголовок в новостях:

> ***Правительство объявило, когда победит бедность***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BC%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F):

> Амфиболи́я (от греч. ἀμφιβολία — двусмысленность, неясность) —
>   двойственность или двусмысленность, получающаяся от того или иного
>   расположения слов или от употребления их в различных смыслах, смешение
>   понятий, обычно связанное с членением предложения.

Пример амфиболии — фраза «Казнить нельзя помиловать», где смысл меняется в зависимости от места паузы после или перед словом «нельзя».

Многочисленные примеры амфиболий дают греческие легенды об оракулах.

Амфиболия может возникнуть при таком построении предложения, когда подлежащее в именительном падеже трудно отличить от прямого дополнения в винительном падеже.

Например:

> ```
> Брега Арагвы и Куры
> Узрели русские шатры.
>
> — А. С. Пушкин. «Евгений Онегин» (Отрывки из Путешествия Онегина)
> ```

А лично мне больше нравится вариант [Звук мотора заглушает реп](http://opencorpora.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA:Andrey_Kruglov/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%85_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

Одним словом, возможно, и не придумали, как её назвать. Пользуют "*неоднозначность между именительным и винительным падежами*" (ещё с родительным такое случается):

http://opencorpora.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_NOUN_nomn_accs_sing

Не читал эту инструкцию по борьбе, но в нашем случае спасает "оно" после "когда".

Comment: Я писал эту инструкцию, но есть и термин в одно слово - Амфиболи́я.